# Navigation Bar in Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-4

I started my Django project a week ago and currently trying to build a **Navigation Bar**.
The source code is:

```
 {% load  static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}" /> 


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!--LOGO-->
        <div class = "navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{%url 'music:index'%}">Pleer...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

{% if all_albums %}
<h3 class="text-muted">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Albums</h3>
<ul>
    {% for album in all_albums %}
    <li class="text-primary"><a href="{%url 'music:detail' album.id %}"><b class="text-danger">{{album.album_title}}</b></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <h2>NO ALBUM FOUND</h2>
{% endif %}
```

but the result is only a simple link with no nav bar. **Am I missing something?**
 Please help me in it.

Comment: add view code, please

Comment: @BearBrown Are you asking for main .html file ?

Comment: i asked about your python code, how you send context.

Answer (score 0):

The nav bar code is fine. 
mention the type

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

and check if bootstrap is loaded. also add

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}" />
```

Comment: everything else is working fine with bootstrap . The problem is only when I am using nav class